# Steel wool around a gas pipe

Tags: pipe, gas, mice

There's a crawl space in my basement where the gas pipe to the stove goes through a hole in the ceiling. I think it might be a big enough hole for a mouse to get through so I'd like to stuff some steel wool in there, which has worked for me against mice before.

My concern is whether having steel wool against a gas pipe is anything to worry about. First, I'm in the US and am only assuming that pipe is steel, so I would think it's OK to do that but is there a reason I shouldn't?

The area is under cover, to the ground, but not insulated. Is rust of the wool a worry?

Comment: I've seen someone mention this stuff before: [Pest Plug](http://steelwooldirect.com/pest-control/) which is a special, rust-free steel wool type mesh made for keeping out rodents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By gas pipe, you mean the gasline--not the actual chimney, right? If so, that is likely steel pipe. It COULD be copper, but you'd be able to tell if that's the case. If it's a steel pipe, stainless steel wool should be fine to plug it.

Comment: Is rusting of the steel wool a concern?

Comment: @Rob that's why you'd use stainless steel wool.

Comment: I tried finding stainless steel wool at HomeDepot and Lowes. Neither carries it but they do have bronze steel wool. It doesn't rust but would it interact with the steel (or iron) gas pipe?

Comment: @Rob I'm not sure about that. It shouldn't be too hard to find stainless steel wool though. I believe my local Ace Hardware had it. Be sure to check in the finishing section (near the stains and such).

Comment: Online they don't show it but there is one down the street so I'll go there later. Thanks.

Comment: @rob Amazon sells it. But locally, you might be better off looking for a 'stainless steel scouring pad' instead: http://www.amazon.com/Scotch-Brite-Stainless-Steel-Scouring-3-Pad/dp/B002CQTXBC/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1444920296&sr=8-1&keywords=steel+wool+stainless

Comment: I found it at Ace in the cleaning supplies area.

Answer (score 0):

With black iron pipe that is normally used for gas pipe I would use spray foam insulation it will expand and fill the voids you won't be able to get to with the steel wool and it will stop air leaks and not rust away even slightly below grade it will seal better and longer than steel wool

Comment: I would but I've read that mice will eat through the foam.

Comment: @Rob they do make rodent-resistent foam (at least it's advertised as such)